# Differences between subqueries and JOIN statements in SQL

Tags: sql, sqlite

LibraryDB is a database system that keeps track of information concerning the books and their circulation in an imaginary library.

The schema for the LibraryDB database is given below:(note that the book_copy relation keeps track of the physical copies of the books in the library collection.)

- borrow(transactionID, personID*, borrowdate, duedate, returndate)
- author(authorID, firstname, middlename, lastname)
- book_copy(bookID, bookdescID*)
- book(bookdescID, title, subtitle, edition, voltitle, volnumber, language, place, year, isbn, dewey, subjectID*)
- borrow_copy(transactionID*, bookID*)
- person(personID, firstname, middlename, lastname, address, city, postcode, phonenumber, emailaddress, studentno, idcardno)
- publisher(publisherID, publisherfullname)
- written_by(bookdescID*, authorID*, role)
- published_by(bookdescID*, publisherID*, role)
- subject(subjectID, subjecttype)

I tried to write two types of SQL statements in SQLite to display the title of books that were never borrowed.

One using the LEFT OUTER JOIN clause:

```
SELECT title
FROM book INNER JOIN book_copy
     ON book.BOOKDESCID = book_copy.BOOKDESCID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN borrow_copy
        ON borrow_copy.BOOKID = book_copy.BOOKID
        WHERE borrow_copy.TRANSACTIONID IS NULL;
```

which returned 323 rows.

One without using the OUTER JOIN clause:

```
SELECT title 
FROM book 
WHERE bookdescID IN 
      (SELECT bookdescID 
       FROM book_copy 
       WHERE bookID NOT IN 
             (SELECT bookID 
              FROM borrow_copy));
```

which only returned 298 rows.

Why these two SQL statements return two different results?

Which one is correct in displaying the title of books that were never borrowed?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between "INNER JOIN" and "OUTER JOIN"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/what-is-the-difference-between-inner-join-and-outer-join)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Both queries were used three tables book, book_copy, and borrow_copy. But the first query:

```
SELECT title
FROM book INNER JOIN book_copy
     ON book.BOOKDESCID = book_copy.BOOKDESCID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN borrow_copy
        ON borrow_copy.BOOKID = book_copy.BOOKID
        WHERE borrow_copy.TRANSACTIONID IS NULL;
```

selected all books with bookdescID in book_copy, and then selected all records from borrow_copy with bookID in book_copy table. I.e. if two records presented in table borrow_copy for one bookID, that increases the count of rows in the output result.

Second query:

```
SELECT title 
FROM book 
WHERE bookdescID IN 
      (SELECT bookdescID 
       FROM book_copy 
       WHERE bookID NOT IN 
             (SELECT bookID 
              FROM borrow_copy));
```

has applied additional filters for the basic table (book).

2. The second query is correct for searching the books that were never borrowed.